# can't figure out what is wrong with Song.FromUri

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I want to load a song with the `Song.FromUri()` method, it works with some files, doesn't work with others. All i could find out is that if i try to play a song from a downloaded album, it won't play, but if i try to play one randomly google'd and downloaded, it plays well. I tried to place the "wrong" file to the Content folder and load it with `Content.Load<Song>("filename")` method, it perfectly plays, but i can't do it that way since it would be a player application, and the user has to choose own files. Any advice?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it won't play"? There's an exception? Or does the song just not play, or is there no sounds, etc?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no exception, it simply does nothing. Anyway, i made another way.